# how to add dropdownlistfor(dynamic object)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have class include the following objects

```
public class ProductViewer
{
    public J_Items Item { get; set; }
    public List<J_ItemsImages> lstItemImages { get; set; }
}
```

how can i add DropDownListFor Item.ItemName

J_Items definition

```
public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string ItemLongDesc { get; set; }
```

Comment: What's the definition of J_Items, can you post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.DropdownlistFor(m => m.Item.ItemName)
```

Where m is your ProductViewer class, of course that should be made in to a viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first argument of the [`Html.DropDownListFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D%29) helper method to designate which property you want to bind to and then use the second to supply a collection to populate the actual drop down list with :

```
<!-- This would bind to the ItemName property, but would populate the list with
     the contents of your lstItemImages property -->
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item.Name, new SelectList(Model.lstItemImages, "Name", "Name"))
```

Likewise, if you had a collection of values on your `J_Items` class, you could access those in the second parameter as well:

```
@Html.DropDownListFOr(m => m.Item.Name, new SelectList(Model.Item.SomeCollection,"Value,"Text")
```

This assumes that your parent `ProductViewer` class would be passed into the view.